# C# DataGridView Virtual Mode: Using CellValuePushed to write Data back to Database

Tags: c#, datagridview, virtualmode

I´m currently trying to implement a virtual DataGridview in a client-server system to increase perfomance.

For that I have used follwing code suggested by Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms171624.aspx

To that point all is fine and is working out as it should. Problem is, the example doesn´t cover writing data back to database. I need users to be able to submit changes. I´ve learned that the CellValuePushed-Event is fired if the user alters any value in the GridView. After searching the web for hours now I still haven´t found a way to accomplish saving data back to database.

Do I have to update the underlying DataTable with the changed value and then refresh the Gridview?

Is there anyone who could help me out with some code or a few hints? Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Ok, I´ve solved this myself now. "Do I have to update the underlying DataTable with the changed value and then refresh the Gridview?" was the right way to accomplish writing the data back to database. Although I´d already tried that, I had missed out on a piece of code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I´ve solved this myself now. "Do I have to update the underlying DataTable with the changed value and then refresh the Gridview?" was the right way to accomplish writing the data back to database. Although I´d already tried that, I had missed out on a piece of code...